# elasticbeanstalk fail to deploy web environment /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I would like to deploy a JAVA application (based on PlayFramework 1.x) on AWS Beanstalk.
I am using a web server environment based on Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.6.

I also added a load balancer in the environment.
During the deployment, my hooks work well (database schema evolutions for example) then comes the time to launch the web server.

The deployment fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] update processes [web cfn-hup nginx healthd] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Track pids in healthd]. Stop running the command. Error: update processes [web cfn-hup nginx healthd] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
```

I don't use any specific configuration for nginx.
I run the JAVA application on the default port (5000).

I saw on the AWS forums and stackoverflow that some people had this problem on worker environments but I don't use this configuration.

Have you ever encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your web.service is not able to start. You might be missing a manifest in your jar, or you might be missing the main class in your manifest file.